# How to Highlight the Competely visible item view in a RecyclerView

Tags: java, android, android-recyclerview, android-adapter

I have an imageView and a textView inside a cardView.
The alpha of the cardView is set to .5f.
The cardView is used in a vertical recyclerView.
What I'm trying to do here is as the user scrolls through the reyclerView the alpha of the completely visible cardView should always change to 1f and for the non-completely visible cardViews alpha stays .5f.
There is only one completely visible cardView at a time.

Here is what I tried but it doesn't work.

```
 @Override
 public void onScrolled(RecyclerView recyclerView, int dx, int dy) {
      super.onScrolled(recyclerView, dx, dy);

      int center = recyclerView.getHeight() / 2;
      View centerView = recyclerView.findChildViewUnder( recyclerView.getTop(), center);
      int centerPos = recyclerView.getChildAdapterPosition(centerView);

       if (prevCenterPos != centerPos) {
            // dehighlight the previously highlighted view
            View prevView = 
           recyclerView.getLayoutManager().findViewByPosition(prevCenterPos);
           if (prevView != null) {
               prevView.setAlpha(.5f);
           }

           // highlight view in the middle
           if (centerView != null) {
                prevView.setAlpha(1f);
           }

           prevCenterPos = centerPos;
        }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

As you are finding center point with this

```
int center = recyclerView.getHeight() / 2;
```

which is not proper way you should use:

```
mLayoutManager.findFirstCompletelyVisibleItemPosition()
```

try this:

```
val firstCompelteVisible = mLayoutManager.findFirstCompletelyVisibleItemPosition()
val centerView =
    recyclerView.layoutManager!!.findViewByPosition(firstCompelteVisible)
if (prevCenterPos != centerPos) {
    // dehighlight the previously highlighted view
    val prevView =
        recyclerView.layoutManager!!.findViewByPosition(prevCenterPos)
    if (prevView != null) {
        prevView.alpha = .5f
    }

    // highlight view in the middle
    if (centerView != null) {
        prevView!!.alpha = 1f
    }
    prevCenterPos = centerPos
}
```

I hope this will work.

Comment: This only works when you scroll down. but when you scroll back up all cardViews alpha is 1f. My code above works when you scroll up and down. The only issue is while scrolling down when I reach position 4(the center view), its alpha changes to1f which is good but then immediately changes back to .5f.